# How to push object keys to an array multiple times based on their integer values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I've looked on several sites including through the suggested answers when posting this question, so forgive me if it's been answered elsewhere. I'm very new to JavaScript (and coding in general). I'm working on a 'weighted lottery' project and I have an approach in mind that I'm sure will work, but am stuck on a particular point.

I have an object which contains the outcomes as object keys and the number of times that particular outcome will be produced as the object values of integer type. Specifically, this:

```
const weights = {
  'win': 5,
  'loss': 10,
  'tie': 3
}
```

I want to push the object keys to an array called 'outcomes' multiple times based on their associated value. For the example above, it would result in an array that lists 'win' 5 times, 'loss' 10 times and 'tie' 3 times.

I have come across the .fill method, but it doesn't seem to work in a situation like this, where I want the number of object items to be dynamic (both in the number of them and their values - i.e. having 15 different 'outcomes' each with different values assigned to them).

Any pointers? Thanks all for this wonderful resource!

Comment: Create the array: `const outcomes = []`; Now iterate and push `Object.entries(weights).forEach(([key, weight) => { for (let i = 0; i < weight; i++) outcomes.push(key); });`

Comment: `[].concat(...Object.keys(weights).map(k => Array(weights[k]).fill(k)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fill` *could* be used for this, but I think I'd just use loops:

```
const outcomes = [];
for (const [key, count] of Object.entries(weights)) {
    for (let n = count; n > 0; --n) {
        outcomes.push(key);
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const weights = {
    "win": 5,
    "loss": 10,
    "tie": 3
};

const outcomes = [];
for (const [key, count] of Object.entries(weights)) {
    for (let n = count; n > 0; --n) {
        outcomes.push(key);
    }
}
console.log(outcomes);
```

<s>But here's how you might use `fill` along with [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) if you wanted to:</s>

```
const outcomes = [];
for (const [key, count] of Object.entries(weights)) {
    outcomes.push(...Array.from({length: count}).fill(key));
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const weights = {
    "win": 5,
    "loss": 10,
    "tie": 3
};

const outcomes = [];
for (const [key, count] of Object.entries(weights)) {
    outcomes.push(...Array.from({length: count}).fill(key));
}
console.log(outcomes);
```

[David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69388709/157247) points to a better way to do the `fill` than that (I'd forgotten about `start` and `end`, doh!), but I would do it slightly differently:

```
const outcomes = [];
for (const [key, count] of Object.entries(weights)) {
    const start = outcomes.length;
    outcomes.length += count;
    outcomes.fill(key, start, outcomes.length);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const weights = {
    "win": 5,
    "loss": 10,
    "tie": 3
};

const outcomes = [];
for (const [key, count] of Object.entries(weights)) {
    const start = outcomes.length;
    outcomes.length += count;
    outcomes.fill(key, start, outcomes.length);
}
console.log(outcomes);
```

That said, the advantage of David's answer is you're telling the JavaScript engine up-front how many elements the array will have, which can be used for optimization. It doesn't often matter, and probably doesn't matter here, but still, it's there.

Comment: I didn't know you could increase the size of an array by literally adding to the `length` property! Fascinating.

Comment: @David - And you can throw away elements by subtracting from it. :-D There are pros and cons, I flagged up one advantage of your approach at the end of the above.

Comment: Well thank you for teaching me something new!

Comment: Thanks everyone! That really cleared it up for me! Should be able to muddle my way through the rest of this now. Wasn't expecting so many answers so quickly! Thanks again and StackOverflow forever!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with fill. You can create a new Array with the combined weights as the length parameter and then fill it like so.

```js
const weights = {
  'win': 5,
  'loss': 10,
  'tie': 3
};

let outcomes = new Array(Object.values(weights).reduce((value, initial) => value+initial));
let pos = 0;
for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(weights))
{
  outcomes.fill(key, pos, pos += value);
}

console.log(outcomes);
```

Comment: Doh! I'd forgotten about `start` and `end`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will be helpful:

```js
const weights = {
  win: 5,
  loss: 10,
  tie: 3
}

const result = []

Object.keys(weights).forEach(name => {
  const times = weights[name]
  result.push(...new Array(times).fill(name))
})

console.log(res)
```